# Determine position given bearing

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

Given a point with **x and y coordinates** in a basic cartesian system, its **relative bearing (-180 <= bearing < 180)** to another point in the system (the bearing is from the line of sight / heading of the robot below) and the distance to the other point, in a clockwise orientation with another point in the following situation.

[image: system2]

How can I determine the position of the previously mentionned other point?

Comment: $(x + r \sin(bearing), y + r \cos(bearing))$ where $r$ is distance between points

Comment: You cannot determine the position of a point in the plane from a single bearing to another point, as this data only constrains the first point to lying on a line through the other point. You need the bearing to *two* points, if bearings are the only data you've got.

Comment: I've edited the original post: we've got the distance to the considered point.

Comment: Take the difference of the angles and apply the formula in Coolwater’s comment.